# jquery percentage calcutaion from the textbox values

Tags: php, jquery, jquery-calculation

[image]i have a form in which i want to take out a percentage on a amount for eg. let the amount be 100 and i will enter 10 so the desired output is 10 and i even want to add the percentage's amount with the amount so the output will be 110 (100 + 10) i am able to take out the percentage but its not being added to the amount and these fields will be the dynamically generated inputs.

Here is my code:

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#detail').on('keyup', '.rent, .stperc, .st, .stamt, .cal', calculateRow);

            function calculateRow() {
                     var $row   = $(this).closest('tr');
                     var value  = parseFloat($row.find('.stperc').val());
                     var value2 = parseFloat($row.find('.rent').val());


                     var stamt  =  parseFloat($row.find('.stamt').val((value * value2) / 100));

                     var cost = stamt + value2;
                     console.log(cost);
                     if (isNaN(cost)) {
                         $row.find('.cal').val("0");
                     } else {
                         $row.find('.cal').val(cost);
                     }

            }

    });
```

Here is my php code which will generate the textboxes:

```
                while ($row = mysql_fetch_object($query)){
                       echo "<tr>";
                       echo "<td align='center'>";
                       echo "<input type='text' class='form-input-rate' name=\"locno_$ctr\" value=\"$row->locno\" $stylen readonly>";
                       echo "</td>";
                       echo "<td align='center'>";
                       echo "<input type='text' class='form-input-rate' name=\"ledger_$ctr\" value=\"$row->custcode\" $stylen readonly>";
                       echo "</td>";
                       echo "<td align='center'>";
                       echo "<input type='text' class='form-input-rate' name=\"name_$ctr\" value=\"$row->name\" $stylev readonly>";
                       echo "</td>";
                       echo "<td align='center'>";
                       echo "<input type='text' class='form-input-rate' name=\"deposit_$ctr\" value=\"$row->deposit\" $stylen >";
                       echo "</td>";
                       echo "<td align='center'>";
                       echo "<input type='text' class='rent form-input-rate' name=\"rent_$ctr\" value=\"$row->rent\" $stylen >";
                       echo "</td>";
                       echo "<td align='center'>";
                       echo "<input type='text' class='stperc form-input-rate' name=\"stperc_$ctr\" value=\"$row->stperc\" $stylen >";
                       echo "</td>";
                       echo "<td align='center'>";
                       echo "<input type='text' class='stamt form-input-rate' name=\"st_$ctr\" value=\"$row->stamt\" $stylen >";
                       echo "</td>";
                       echo "<td align='center'>";
                       echo "<input type='text' class='cal form-input-rate' name=\"total_$ctr\" value=\"$row->totamt\" $stylen readonly>";
                       echo "<input type='hidden' name=\"accode_$ctr\" value=\"$row->accode\">";
                       echo "</td>";
                       echo "</tr>"; 
                       $ctr++;
                }
```

Comment: make fiddle of your code

Comment: see i have added my php code too

Comment: i have posted a screnshot of my output

Answer (score 0):

try something like this [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/rajesh007/6jga8/2/)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#detail').on('keyup', '.rent, .stperc, .st, .stamt, .cal', function(){
        var $row   = $(this).closest('tr');
        var value  = parseFloat($row.find('.stperc').val());
        var value2 = parseFloat($row.find('.rent').val());
        var stamt = (value * value2) / 100;
        $row.find('.stamt').val(stamt);
        var cost = stamt + value2;
        if (isNaN(cost)) {
            $row.find('.cal').val("rasd");
        } else {
            $row.find('.cal').val(cost);
        }

   });

});
```

Comment: Sorry for wrong jquery version . check this one http://jsfiddle.net/rajesh007/6jga8/1/

Comment: i think u dint got my question right sir my query is that the output from the percentage is not getting added up with the amount